# Passing `kerncharacters` to `defineframedtext`

Tags: context

I am designing Word search grids with ConTeXt. I use monospace fonts, but additionnal kerning helps reading the grid.
I was wondering how can I define some framed text with additionnal kerning being added between each letter.

EDIT: I discovered an error in my first MWE, that made me discover the `kerncharacters` command on the wiki. How can I pass`\kerncharacters` to `defineframedtext`?

```
\defineframedtext [Grille]
   [style={\ttb},
    bodyfont=14pt,
    width=fit,
    location=left]
\starttext

ABCD
\startGrille
\kerncharacter[0.25]
ABCD\par
EFGH
\stopGrille

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply the `\kerncharacters` commands to the whole context of the `framedtext` environment you can pass it as argument to the `style` key.

```
\defineframedtext
  [Grille]
  [style={\tt\kerncharacters[1]},
   bodyfont=20pt,
   width=fit,
   location=left]

\starttext

\startGrille
ABCD\\
EFGH\\
\stopGrille

\stoptext
```

Another way to increase the distance between the letters is to change width of the characters itself, this can be achieved with the `dimension` font feature.

```
\definefontfeature [equalwidth] [dimensions={1.5,*,*}]

\definefont [EqualWidth] [MonoBold*default,equalwidth]

\defineframedtext
  [Grille]
  [style=EqualWidth,
   bodyfont=20pt,
   width=fit,
   location=left]

\starttext

\startGrille
ABCD\\
EFGH\\
\stopGrille

\stoptext
```

Comment: Solved, thanks! One detail: playing with your first answer, I cannot see the difference between `\tt\characterkerning[1]` and `\tt\characterkerning[0.5]`. Any idea why?

Comment: Make a few copies of the `Grille` block and apply different values to `\kerncharacters` (e.g. `\startGrille[style={\tt\kerncharacters[0.5]}] ... \stopGrille`) to see the different spacing, it's sometimes hard to see the differeneces when you switch between text editor and PDF viewer.

Comment: That helped, thanks!